# How do I draw perfectly straight lines in stage builder?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

As the title says -- I'm having issues drawing completely straight lines using my fingers in the stage builder. I'm trying to draw a hexagon, but obviously it's pretty difficult to make any shape that isn't a rectangle or a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to draw straight lines in Stage Builder:

- Hold <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> while drawing
- Enable the grid with <kbd>-</kbd> to make lines snap to the grid
- Tap a point on the screen to start a line, then tap where you want the line to end

Source: [smashfan63](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/bgm7jo/how_to_draw_straight_lines_in_smash_ultimate/ellxp71/) & testing on my own Switch

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Y</kbd> (well, the one on the switch) to bring up different layers and from there activate the grid and make it much easier to draw shapes!

Comment: You can also hold L or R while drawing to get straight lines or tap where you want to start the line and then tap again where you want it to end.